# Tomcat can't see js-script

Tags: javascript, web, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am developing web-project using servlets and jsp. I am building the project in intellij. In the project I have one jsp that manage graphics and user form. `graphics.js` is responsible for the graphics and for form validation - `validator.js`.

My problem: Tomcat works correctly with `graphics.js` but he can't find the `validator.js`. In the console, I have a 404 message that says there is no `validator.js`, although it is in the same folder as the `graphics.js`.

I would be very grateful for an explanation of this situation. I found similar questions, but the answers to them did not help me. I apologize if I repeat one of them

The project structure:

```
src
  ControllerServlet.java
  AreaCheckingServlet.java
web
  css
    style.css
  js
    graphics.js
    validator.js
  WEB-INF
    Form.jsp
    web.xml
```

Form.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style><%@include file="/css/style.css"%></style>
    <title>web-lab-2</title>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/graphics.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/validator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="canvas" class="one_line">
    <canvas id="graphics" height="600px" width="600px"></canvas>
    <script>draw(600, 240, 25)</script>
</div>
<div id="input_column" class="one_line">
    <form class="js-form">
        <div id="x" class="input">
            <p>choose the value of x</p>
            <input id="x=-4" name="x" type="radio" value="-4">
            <label for="x=-4">-4</label><br>
            <input id="x=-3" name="x" type="radio" value="-3">
            <label for="x=-3">-3</label><br>
            <input id="x=-2" name="x" type="radio" value="-2">
            <label for="x=-2">-2</label><br>
            <input id="x=-1" name="x" type="radio" value="-1">
            <label for="x=-1">-1</label><br>
            <input id="x=0" name="x" type="radio" value="0">
            <label for="x=0">0</label><br>
            <input id="x=1" name="x" type="radio" value="1">
            <label for="x=1">1</label><br>
            <input id="x=2" name="x" type="radio" value="2">
            <label for="x=2">2</label><br>
            <input id="x=3" name="x" type="radio" value="3">
            <label for="x=3">3</label><br>
            <input id="x=4" name="x" type="radio" value="4">
            <label for="x=4">4</label><br>
        </div>
        <div id="y" class="input">
            <p></p>
            <label for="y-inp">choose the value of y</label>
            <p></p>
            <input id="y-inp" name="y" type="text" placeholder="type a number between -3 and 5" class="y">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="r-group" class="input">
            <input id="r=1" name="r" type="checkbox" value="1">
            <label for="r=1">1</label><br>
            <input id="r=2" name="r" type="checkbox" value="2">
            <label for="r=2">2</label><br>
            <input id="r=3" name="r" type="checkbox" value="3">
            <label for="r=3">3</label><br>
            <input id="r=4" name="r" type="checkbox" value="4">
            <label for="r=4">4</label><br>
            <input id="r=5" name="r" type="checkbox" value="5">
            <label for="r=5">5</label><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="submit">Send</label><br>
            <input id="submit" type="button" onclick="validate()">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

graphics.js:

```
function draw(side, r, mar) {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("graphics")
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

    context.fillStyle = (30, 30, 30)
    context.globalAlpha = 0.15
    context.fillRect(0, 0, side, side)

    context.fillStyle = "blue"
    context.globalAlpha = 0.65
    context.fillRect(side / 2, side / 2, r, -r / 2)

    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(side / 2, side / 2, r, 0, Math.PI / 2)
    context.moveTo(side / 2, side / 2)
    context.lineTo(side / 2 + r, side / 2)
    context.lineTo(side / 2, side / 2 + r)
    context.fill()

    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(side / 2, side / 2)
    context.lineTo(side / 2 - r / 2, side / 2)
    context.lineTo(side / 2, side / 2 + r)
    context.fill()

    context.fillStyle = "black"
    context.globalAlpha = 1;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0, side / 2);
    context.lineTo(side, side / 2);
    context.moveTo(side / 2, 0);
    context.lineTo(side / 2, side);
    context.stroke();

    context.font = '20px monospace'
    context.fillText('-R', side / 2 - r, side / 2 + mar)
    context.fillText('-R/2', side / 2 - r / 2, side / 2 + mar)
    context.fillText('0', side / 2 - mar * 0.75, side / 2 + mar)
    context.fillText('R/2', side / 2 + r / 2, side / 2 + mar)
    context.fillText('R', side / 2 + r, side / 2 + mar)
    context.fillText('R', side / 2 - mar * 0.75, side / 2 - r)
    context.fillText('R/2', side / 2 - mar * 1.5, side / 2 - r / 2)
    context.fillText('-R/2', side / 2 - mar * 2, side / 2 + r / 2)
    context.fillText('-R', side / 2 - mar * 1.25, side / 2 + r)

    console.log("done")
}
```

validator.js(there is only a message about the correct work for debugging yet):

```
function validate() {
    console.log("donedone")
}
```

I tried to change the directory with js-scripts, change URLs in the code to "/js/validator.js", "js/validator.js" and "../js/validator.js" (it is worth noting that the `graphics.js` was correctly located with all these paths), also I tried to search  `validator.js` directly by "localhost:8080/js/validator.js". This didn't work either, but "localhost:8080/js/graphics.js " works.

UPD: I also tried rebuild/clean artefacts. And recreating the project from 0 too

Comment: It seems to be IDE related problem. Rebuild/clean artefacts.

Comment: I also tried this. And recreating the project from 0 too

Comment: If you check build output directory can you see validator.js there? How is your artifact configured?

Comment: I created artifact using automatic generation by Intellij. validator.js is located correctly in out directory.

Comment: Then last thing you can check is Run/Debug  Tomcat configuration, check deployment tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't understand what the error was. But it helped me to replace the old lines of code:

```
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/graphics.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/validator.js"></script>
```

with these:

```
    <script><%@include file="/js/graphics.js"%></script>
    <script><%@include file="/js/validator.js"%></script>
```

UPD: After some research, I assume that the problem was the lack of Tomcat permission to use files from my project folder.